# Google groups -'Resource Not Found: groupKey'

Tags: node.js, google-workspace, google-groups

I have tried every possibility but haven't got any solution to solve this.
I am using JWT for authentication

My code is

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')

const credentials = require('./credentials.json')
const SCOPE = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group'
];

const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
  credentials.client_email,
  null,
  credentials.private_key,
  SCOPE
);

jwt.authorize((err, response) => {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  console.log("You have been successfully authenticated: ");
  ggrun(jwt);
});

async function ggrun(cl) {

  var googleGroups = google.admin({version: "directory_v1", auth: cl});

  try {

    const users = await getGoogleGroupsUsers();


  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error);
  }

  /**
   * Get Google Groups Users
   */

  async function getGoogleGroupsUsers() {

    const opt = {
      groupKey: 'testing-infoxen@googlegroups.com'
    }

    try {

      const user = await googleGroups.groups.get(opt);

      console.log('user: ', user);

    } catch( error ) {
      console.log('err: ', error);
    }
  }

}
```

and every time I am getting this error

> { domain: 'global',
>          reason: 'notFound',
>          message: 'Resource Not Found: groupKey' }

Can you please help me Or suggest to me where the problem is?